# segmentation of overlapping cells

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

The following python script should split overlapping cells apart which does work quite good. The problem is now that it also splits some of the cells apart which don't overlap with other cells. To make things clear to you i'll add my input image and the output image.

The input:[input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENnGl.png)

The output:
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAQGp.png)

Output image where I marked two "bad" segmented cells:[Output image with marked errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyW6J.jpg)

Thresholded image: [Thresholded image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KliEl.jpg)

**Does someone have an idea how to avoid this problem or is the whole approach not good enough to process these kind of images?**

I am using the following piece of code to segment the cells:

```
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage.morphology import watershed
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np
import cv2


# load the image and perform pyramid mean shift filtering
# to aid the thresholding step
image = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Root/Desktop/image13.jpg')
shifted = cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(image, 41, 51)

# convert the mean shift image to grayscale, then apply
# Otsu's thresholding
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
im = gray.copy()    
D = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(thresh)
localMax = peak_local_max(D, indices=False, min_distance=3,  
    labels=thresh)
# perform a connected component analysis on the local peaks,
# using 8-connectivity, then apply the Watershed algorithm
markers = ndimage.label(localMax, structure=np.ones((3, 3)))[0]
labels = watershed(-D, markers, mask=thresh)
print("[INFO] {} unique segments found".format(len(np.unique(labels)) - 1))

conts=[]    
for label in np.unique(labels):
    # if the label is zero, we are examining the 'background'
    # so simply ignore it
    if label == 0:
        continue
    # otherwise, allocate memory for the label region and draw
    # it on the mask
    mask = np.zeros(gray.shape, dtype="uint8")
    mask[labels == label] = 255
    # detect contours in the mask and grab the largest one
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)  
    if cv2.contourArea(c) > 150: 
        #cv2.drawContours(image,c,-1,(0,255,0))
        cv2.drawContours(image,[box],-1,(0,255,0))      
cv2.imshow("output", image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: This is typically a good approach, but don't expect a perfect result. There exist no methods that always produce perfect results. That said, this is a relatively simple image, and you can get better results out. Is the binarization good enough? Can you tell individual cells apart there? You might need a better preprocessing if not.

Comment: I've added the thresholded image to the question. I can get better results for single cells when I increase the min_distance in the peak_local_max function. But if I do so, the big cluster of cells won't be segmented at all. Do you have any suggestions for a better preprocessing?

Comment: Yes, you can do better preprocessing than that. Mean shift filtering is not ideal. If directly thresholding doesn't give good results, try applying a closing filter before thresholding (and convert to grey value before filtering). Honestly, this is mostly a trial-and-error type of thing, experience helps in knowing what filters might be useful, but it's different every time. :)